# How to change the icon of the form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am new to c#. I have design two forms first the main form and second form is a popup form which include two buttons only. I only want that on different occasions i mean on pressing different buttons on main form the look of popup form should be little bit changed so for that purpose i want to change the icon of popup form
Here is the code

```
Alert popeup = new Alert();
popeup.Icon = email.Properties.Resources.run;
```

`popeup` is object of that popup form through this code i am getting a error `Can not implicitly convert type System.Drawing.Bitmap to System.Drawing.Icon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work fine

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(email.Properties.Resources.run);  
IntPtr Hicon = bmp.GetHicon();  
Icon myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the data type of **email.properties.Resources.run** is a bitmap format, and the **popeup.icon** is expecting an icon format.     Can you use an editing tool and make an icon version of the file and load that into your resource instead?

Comment: but the file name `run` is not in bitmap format it is in `.ico` format

Comment: Looks like Mike's answer works.   It run is actually an icon, check where it is declared, since it must be declared as a bitmap, which is what causes the error message.